# Deploying 4.5 code on iis 7

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

I am trying  to deploy application made in framework in  4.5  on IIS 7  application pool 4.0

and i am  facing the below error ::

`The 'targetFramework' attribute in the  element of the Web.config file is used only to target version 4.0 and later of the .NET Framework (for example, ''). The 'targetFramework' attribute currently references a version that is later than the installed version of the .NET Framework. Specify a valid target version of the .NET Framework, or install the required version of the .NET Framework.`

Comment: Didn't deployed 4.5 apps to the server but I think I can't changed that tag to 4.5 since the core in the server is either 2 or 4. (there isn't 3 or 3.5 too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to

> Specify a valid target version of the .NET Framework, or install the required version of the .NET Framework.